# When hover the Selected image, the selected Image pops up

Tags: jquery, html, image

My Code is pure html with few javascript.I have some sets of image all i need when hover the image it pops up like in a big picture or with same size

HTML Code:

```
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid lastgrid">
     <img src="../images2.jpg" title="ocean" />
     <img src="../images3.jpg" title="pool" />
</div>
```

When users hover the image,the image pops up this is all i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
    -o-transform: scale(1.2);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

Try this one. I think this is the proper way to do it. Just increase or decrease the number inside the scale.

Answer (score 0):

Image become bigger on hover,

```css
img {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
 
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
     -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
       -o-transition: all 1s ease;
      -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
          transition: all 1s ease;
}

img:hover {
  width: 220px;
  height: 220px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-box-left-bootomgrid lastgrid">
  <img src="https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/styles/image_card_4x3_ratio/public/thumbnails/image/25126583741_d7db3f6905_o.jpg?itok=jYAcBCmb" title="ocean" />
  <img src="http://www.menucool.com/slider/jsImgSlider/images/image-slider-2.jpg" title="pool" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one more example:

```css
.div1 {
  width: 320px;
  height: 240px;
}
.div2image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.div2image img {
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  -o-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}
.div2image:hover img {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.25);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.25);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.25);
  -o-transform: scale(1.25);
  transform: scale(1.25);
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2image">
    <img src="https://openclipart.org/download/69331/HTML-Icon-Final.svg" alt="Some awesome text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

> Tested on:

- chrome
- firefox
- IE11